# How to upload image from Webcam.js in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I have used [Webcam.js](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) in a basic example script.

When I click the 'capture' button it shows the image from webcam in `<img src='data:image/jpeg64,........'>`.

I need to upload the image from attribute `src` to my server.

Usually, I can upload files into server by `<input name="file" type="file">`, but in this case I can not do it.
Please help.

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not forget to provide some code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and format your question properly, using the [provided markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Trying to find and clarify the question.

Comment: may be this one can help you http://codingbin.com/capture-webcam-image-with-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score -2):

Parse JSON and get all text in '..'.
Then decode image from base64.

Comment: The explanation is not enough, can you include the code to do it?